# mui some styles not working on first load of app || on first time load reactjs app mui button styles not working on mui modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

I'm using `"@mui/material": "^5.14.2","@mui/styles": "^5.14.13",` on first load of modal button and autocomplete styles not working properly. Below is just example of modal I'm using, It rendered when the component rendered but the modal visible when `open` will true, one open mange by React.useState hook.

```
 <Modal
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        >
          <Box sx={style}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: "column",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  gap: "15px",
                  border: "0px solid blue",
                }}
              >
                <Typography
                  sx={{
                    color: "#2B2A2C",
                    fontSize: "30px",
                    fontWeight: 600,
                  }}
                >
                  Add Details
                </Typography>
                <TextField
                  sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                  label="Name"
                  name="name"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
                <TextField
                  sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                  label="password"
                  variant="outlined"
                  name="password"
                />
              </Box>
              <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <Stack
                  direction={"row"}
                  justifyContent={"right"}
                  spacing={2}
                  sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                >
                  <Button
                    sx={{
                      borderRadius: "6px",
                      background: "#1E0D61",
                      color: "#fff",
                      textTransform: "none",
                      "&:hover": { background: "#220986" },
                    }}
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    Save
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    onClick={handleClose}
                    sx={{
                      borderRadius: "6px",
                      background: "#FE9A25",
                      color: "#fff",
                      textTransform: "none",
                      "&:hover": { background: "#e9983c" },
                    }}
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </Button>
                </Stack>
              </Box>
            </form>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
```

when i fresh the app then all styles working properly,
please anyone help how can I resolve this issue,

at first load all mui style should work properly

Comment: Please send codesandbox link for your project, create one demo in the codesandbox and send us a link. So, we can look into the issue.